# Django Cache: How to ignore HTTP_ACCEPT header?

Tags: django, caching, django-middleware

**While using Django's built-in caching how can I generate the cache key only on the basis of the URL, ignoring small differences in the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header?**

---

In Safari the `HTTP_ACCESS` header's Value is `'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'`

but in Chrome it is 
`'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'`

---

Since `_generate_cache_key` in `utils/cache.py` uses the Value of `HTTP_ACCESS` header to generate the cache key, these are saved as two distinct cache keys and the view has to call the original SQL queries twice over, instead of using the cached value.

---

**How can I ignore the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header entirely, so the caching is done only on URL (and URL parameters)?.**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366405/monkey-patch-django-util-cache-function) question, and possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940592/technique-for-subclassing-django-updatecachemiddleware-and-fetchfromcachemiddlew), but it is unclear if and how to proceed with subclassing `_generate_cache_key`